# I want to change the default app for a specific protocol ('roblox') to launch multiple Roblox UWP apps on my system

Tags: uwp, protocols, roblox

I want to make a tool which will launch multiple roblox uwp apps, but the apps use same protocol 'roblox'. Because I want to have a control of what app I want to launch, so I want to change the default app. I know this can be done with Settings>Apps>Default Apps but I want to do this with powershell too.

I didn't find a method to do this, so I need ur help